# Multiply two arrays gives wrong result

Tags: c#, arrays

I just have two simple arrays of double Values! I get the input from the user and the size of the arrays are equal (always). The thing is, I am multiplying them using:

```
int sizeof_secondarray = entArray.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i <sizeof_secondarray; i++)
        {
          prod = freqArray[i] * entArray[i];
          Console.WriteLine("PROD= " + prod.ToString("#.##"));
        }
```

So, the user gives input for array (freqArray) 50 & 60
and for the array (entArray) 0.52 & 0.47

but the product it gives me is:

```
 PROD= 
 PROD= 23.5
 PROD=
```

I am totally new to c# and missing something badly here, can somebody help me please?

Comment: Are you sure the arrays are typed as integers? If they do, they cannot possibly contain 0.52 and 0.47. Can you show where these arrays are declared and populated? And where `prod` is declared?

Comment: Also: note that 50 x .47 is 23.5 - so at least one result makes sense

Comment: You have done int_entArray.Lenght instead of Length. I'm guessing this is a typo here.

Comment: please dont mind them as by their names my both arrays are of type double at the declaration actually I'm testing the code

Comment: Its multiplying the first element of first array with second element of second array.

Comment: Can you add the code here, where you are taking the inputs into the arrays?

Comment: Have you tried without the formatting? So without `.ToString("#.##")`. So you know the exact value you are getting.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of prod?

Comment: prod is of type double!

Comment: The fact that your WriteLine statement executes three times points to a possible error in the composition of your entArray. Can you debug and confirm that sizeof_secondary is 2?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your partial code and your inputs, I see three points here:

1- The length of your arrays are 3, since you have three outputs, while you mentioned providing only 2 numbers per array. Thus there are some errors when you fill the arrays.

2- Since prod.ToString("#.##") returned empty strings in first and third printout, it means that entArray[0]*freqArray[0] and entArray[2]*freqArray[2] are zeros (x.ToString("#.##") returns empty string when x=0).

3- Based on 1 and 2, my blind guess is that your arrays are filled like this: {0,50,60} and 
{0.52,0.47,0}, leading to the shown result.

Conclusion: Fix the section of the code where you get inputs from the user. There is absolutely no problem with the code section you provided here.

Answer (score -1):

Change the for loop to below and try

```
for (int i = 0;i <sizeof_secondarray - 1; i++)
```

**Update :**

Sorry i overlooked into the question and gave wrong suggestion. I have tested the scenario using below code and it gave me correct answer. Are you declaring the variables, specifically "prod" in the below manner? Below code may give some hint to you.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] entArray = new double[] { 0.52, 0.47 };

        int sizeof_secondarray = entArray.Length;

        double prod;
        double[] freqArray = new double[] { 50, 40};          

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof_secondarray; i++)
        {
            prod = freqArray[i] * entArray[i];
            Console.WriteLine("PROD= " + prod.ToString("#.##"));
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

**Answer :**

```
PROD= 26
PROD= 18.8
```